# Spring Boot CORS url top level domain/path not working

Tags: spring-boot, cors, cross-domain

Testing CORS with the following code(*`spring boot 1.7`*):

```
registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://example.com", "http://example.org");
```

If I try an origin header like `http://example.com` it works perfectly, the problem comes when I use a url indicating a port(`http://example.com:8990`), an app context (`http://example.com/myApp`) or a path (`http://example.com/theSuperApp/get/catalogs`), in any other case when is not the exact origin string it returns error, any idea how to allow any url like the ones bellow?:

```
https://example.org/
http://example.org:9080
http://example.org/aModule
http://example.org/aModule/submodule/subSubModule
http://example.org:80765/aModule/submodule/subSubModule
```

No need to say I don't want to provide all the possible url paths since new ones are added with time

Answer (score -1):

When using declarative configuration like that you have to add all possible combinations of origins or use `"*"` to allow all.

Origin includes the protocol scheme, domain and port.

Comment: 1) If I wanted to allow all, there would be pointless enabling CORS.
2) As I mentioned, adding all possible values might be a hassle(present and future), specially when I want to allow only 2 domains with any app context and path.